# css for creating dropdown not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a Drop down using CSS. I not sure why my css is not applying.
I have created UL and LI elements for rendering the dropdown.
Please see the screenshot of the output when it is rendered. Using developer tools.

[image]

Below is the code

**CSS**

```
ul 
{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li ul li a
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

li ul
{
    display: none;
}

ul li a 
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #2C5463;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover 
{
    background: #617F8A;
}
hideli li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

hideli li:hover li
{
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}

li:hover a 
{
    background: #617F8A;
}

li:hover li a:hover 
{
    background: #95A9B1;
}
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.mobile.all.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/angular.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jszip.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#"><img  src="~/Images/Computacenter.png" /> </a> 
                    <h1>MCR</h1>


                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Requests</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Activities</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Reports</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Admin</p></a></li>


                        <li class="hideli">
                            @*<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">*@
                                @*<select class="form-control">
                                    <option><a href="#">ALL</a></option>
                                    <option><a href="#">DE</a></option>
                                    <option><a href="#">GB</a></option>
                                    <option><a href="#">FR</a></option>
                                </select>*@
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">ALL</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">DE</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">GB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">FR</a></li>

                            </ul>

                            @*<div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn  dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    Dropdown Example
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>*@

                                <p>Country</p>
                            @*</a>*@
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Save View</p></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

    </header>

    <div id="body">

            @RenderBody()

    </div>

    @*<div id="body">



        <section class="content-wrapper  clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>*@

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hideli in the css should be .hideli. A Fiddle would help though.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap 3

Comment: sorry I dont know to use fiddle

Comment: Basically The look and feel of the combo box has to be same as the other menu items

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the  section? You need that for it to work

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its already been referenced. I had shared only a snipped of the file.  I have updated the file to contain the whole code